# Eclipse: New Java class wizard: Why doesn't it always fill in package?

Tags: eclipse

When creating new Java classes, my copy of Eclipse doesn't put them in a package. It gives me a warning about not putting the class in the default package, but it doesn't give me any other options.

I've seen other people use Eclipse, and their copy of Eclipse defaults them to a package named after the project they just created. I can't figure out why my copy of Eclipse is acting differently.

Here's what I'm doing:

1. File -> New -> Java Project
2. Name the project "quickTest". Leave everything else the same ("use default location" checked, JRE as JavaSE-16, Project Layout as "Create separate folders", Working sets unchecked, "Create module-info.java" checked). Press Finish.
3. Hit "Create" on the "Create module-info.java" popup, using the default module name "quickTest"
4. File -> New -> Class

In the "New Java Class" dialog, the package is blank and there's a warning about "The use of the default package is discouraged". If I hit "Browse...", "default package" is the only option.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get Eclipse to auto-create a "quicktest" package when it creates the project, in the way I've seen it do for other people?

Yes, I know I could manually create the package afterwards, but I'd rather not have to do an extra step.

This is Eclipse 2021-06 (4.20.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the owner of the other computer showed me the trick. Apparently, it matters *how* you start the new class wizard.

If you create a new class by right-clicking on the project in the Package Explorer, it will fill in the package name automatically. But if you create the new class from the File menu, it doesn't.

So, this works:

1. File -> New -> Project
2. Name the project "quickTest". Leave everything else the same (see above). Press Finish.
3. Hit "Create" on the "Create module-info.java" popup, using the default module name "quickTest"
4. **Right click on the project name in Package Explorer** -> New -> Class

The package name will be filled in with "quickTest".

(Apparently, this only works if the project name starts with a lower-case letter.)

Honestly, it feels like a bug that it works one way and not the other, but that's how you avoid needing to manually add a new package.

Answer (score 0):

A new project does not have any packages defined. For the very first class you create in a project just type the package you want directly in the "Package" field of the New Class dialog. Eclipse will create the package folders and create the class in the package.

For subsequent classes you create the package will be filled in.

You can always type a package name in the Package field if you want to create a new package.